# MasterDetailPage with a stack

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Navigating from one content page to master detail page and pop the master detail page (remove the master detail page) to another content page.

So basically here's the scenario.

Page 1 -> Page 2 -> Page 3 -> MasterDetailPage -> Page 4

So what I've tried was doing this.

Navigation to page 1 to 3 would be:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("PageX");
```

Then navigating to MasterDetailPage would be:

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterDetail/NavigationPage/MainPage");
```

So this gives me a stack on top of the master detail page.

Then let's say I have a log out button navigating to a certain page by using absolute navigation:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("/Page4");
```

I am getting unhandled exception when navigating to page 4

However, when I do this to App.xaml.cs:

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterDetail/NavigationPage/MainPage");
```

And navigate back to Page 4, I do not encounter the exception. Can anyone enlighten me how do I navigate using a master detail that has a stack on top of it?

**EDIT1: Fixed the issue [Here's the link](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1208) to what I did.**

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: According to your code it should just work. It is however important that all the pages inherit from the correct types. Would it be possible to put the souce on GitHub somewhere, or maybe provide more information about your pages?

Comment: @NickN. I've fixed the issue, sorry for not updating my post [Here's the link](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1208) for the solution

Comment: @RexHope No problem, by the way: it would be better to post your solution (with some code) as an answer to your own question instead of editing the question.

Comment: @NickN. Sure, I'll do that tomorrow. Thanks.